# Laravel How to get Route Profile based on Route Name

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.4, router

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/test',['as'=>'test','custom_key'=>'custom_value','uses'=>'TestController@index'])
```

I've been tried to use `$routeProfile=route('test');`
But the result is returned url `string http://domain.app/test`

I need `['as'=>'test','custom_key'=>'custom_value']` so that I can get the `$routeProfile['custom_key']`

How can I get 'custom_value' based on route name ?

Comment: Here `custom_key` means what?

Comment: Hi @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, I add it manually as like some flagging for route profile. Maybe I can add 'description' or 'parent' or 'is_displayed' for menu hierarchy.

Comment: I've added answer with two different way, you can choose as per you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fastest way, now I use this for my question:

```
function routeProfile($routeName)
{
    $routes = Route::getRoutes();
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $action = $route->getAction();
        if (!empty($action['as']) && $routeName == $action['as']) {
            $action['methods'] = $route->methods();
            $action['parameters'] = $route->parameters();
            $action['parametersNames'] = $route->parametersNames();
            return $action;
        }
    }
}
```

If there's any better answer, I will be appreciate it.
Thanks...

Comment: Still, there isn't any better way to do this. +1 upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

$customKey = Route::current()->getAction()['custom_key'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a way to pass variable to your route

```
Route::get('/test/{custom_key}',[
    'uses'=>'TestController@index',
    'as'=>'test'
]);
```

You could generate a valid URL like so using 
`route('test',['custom_key'=>'custom_key_vale'])`

In your view:

```
<a href="{route('test',['custom_key'=>'custom_key_vale'])}"
```

In your controller method:

```
....

public function test(Request $request)
{
   $custom_key = $request->custom_key;
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the below code:
**1.** Add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` after namespace line code

```
public function welcome(Request $request)
{
    $request->route()->getAction()['custom_key'];
}
```

**2. OR with a facade**

Add `use Route;` after `namespace` line code

and use below into your method

```
public function welcome()
{
    Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction()['custom_key'];
}
```

Both are tested and working fine!